# Codeigniter - where primary key is used by child table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables `blog` and `category`, where `blog.categoryid=category.id`. In the below snippet I am obtaining list of active categories with atleast one blog post.

```
$this->db->select('c.*',FALSE);
$this->db->from('category c');
$this->db->where('c.cattype','posts');
$this->db->where('c.activefrom <=', date('Y-m-d'));
/* TODO - where category has atleast one blog post */
$this->db->limit(10,$offset);
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();
```

The above snippet provides the active category list, but I need to achieve list of active categories with atleast one blog post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you join (inner join) `category` table to `blog` table and group by `category.id`, then you have a list of categories with at least one blog post.

Add these lines:

```
$this->db->join('blog', 'blog.categoryid = category.id');
$this->db->group_by('c.id');
```

More information at: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html